# ssrs report display blank on browser for 2997 rows of data and stored procedure timing is 42 secounds

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, reportingservices-2005

all data displayed in stored procedure but not in SSRS report on internet explorer,2997 rows of data and stored procedure timing is 42 secounds. if filter is applied then working properly but if by default all is selected then can't display.

Comment: Can you add a sample of the data, and add the query - otherwise we're working in the dark with what's causing your problem...

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a problem within the multi parameter within the stored procedure.

You will need to create a function on the server to split the comma-delimited string into values that can be used in “IN” clause or operator.

Example can be found at :[enter link description here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8b1d7132-4b57-4037-b673-95bdf8196d95/parameter-with-multi-values-not-working-in-ssrs?forum=sqlreportingservices)